# get date from float number in php or jquery

Tags: php, jquery, date

I am working on a project in which i have to Generate a Date from Selected Option value.

Example:

1. If selected **`1.5`** then need a date after **1** Month **15** days **`15-08-2017`**
2. If selected **`1.0`** then need a date after **1** Month **`17-08-2017`**

   ```
   <select class="form-control" name="days" id="days" required>
       <option data-days="1.5" value="3">After 1 month 15 days</option>
       <option data-days="2.5" value="4">After 2 month 15 days</option>
       <option data-days="6.0" value="10">After 5 month</option>
       <option data-days="7.5" value="30">After 7 month 15 days</option>       
       //And So on...
   </select>

   // Here is the script for getting selected option days attribute.
   $('body').on('change', '#days', function(e) {
       var days = $(this).find(':selected').data('days');

       // Now How do i get the date according the days. as shown in example

   });
   ```

I have also tried to get the date in `PHP` but i didn't get it.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1.0 month'));
```

So can anyone help me to get date using this `float` numbers in `PHP` or `Jquery`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 month", $time));
```

you can use this. for 1 month

or

for adding 1 day

```
$final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", $time));
```

for adding more than one day
       $final_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+15 day", strtotime($date)));

```
$float_number = '4.5'; 

$nubers = explode('.', $float_number); 

$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.$nubers[0].' month')); 

if($nubers[1] == '0'){ 

$final_date = $date; 

} else { 

$final_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+15 day", strtotime($date))); 

} 

print_r("Final Date: ".$final_date);
```

Comment: `$final = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+6.0 month", $time));`  I have tried this but it did not give me correct date it gives me current date

Comment: remove the .0 keep only 6 or 5 month, as i gave in answer

Comment: i am getting this float number from database and even if i change it then what about `1.5` or `6.5` values. it is not working

Comment: bro iff you are getting 6.5 that means 6 months and 15 days right? so you have to add 6 month first, then add 15 days with the result, do you get it?

Comment: ok i get what you are saying but it will add more complexity to my code the i have to check for each values in the loop that it has `.0` of `.5`. ok i will try it and get back to you sir. thank you for help.

Comment: as working on your suggestion now i have a two date so how do i get the sum of two dates.

Answer (score 1):

you can add days instead of month in option value. so if 1.5 month than add 45 days(1.5 * 30).

```
<option data-days="45" value="3">After 1 month 15 days</option>
<option data-days="75" value="4">After 2 month 15 days</option>
<option data-days="180" value="10">After 5 month</option>
<option data-days="225" value="30">After 7 month 15 days</option>
```

And inside PHP you can add days for feature date.

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+30 days", $time));
```

In javascript you can use below solution.

```js
    var time = new Date();
    time.setDate(time.getDate()+30);
    console.log(time);
```

This will help you.

Comment: is it any suggestion for `jquery` to get the date from `float` number.

Comment: Your float is month, so you can covert it into days by `*30`